# How to add each element of Vec?

Tags: chisel

For example, let's assume that I have following data:

```
class VectorElemAdd extends Module {
  val io = IO (new Bundle {
    val input = Input(Vec(64, UInt(64.W)))
    val out = Output(UInt(64.W))
  })

  /*
    if the vector data is : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 63,
    I have to add each element : 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + 63 by indexing Vec,
    for example : input(0) + input(1) + ... + input(63),
    But, it needs kind of for loop to add all elements of Vec

    and the final output(io.out) will be the input(0) + input(1) + ... + 
    input(63)
  */
```

The things that I need to do are described in the comment. Is it possible to such kind of operation easily?(for example, using for loop or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular problem is very easy to represent in Scala.

```
class VectorElemAdd extends Module {
  val io = IO (new Bundle {
    val input = Input(Vec(64, UInt(64.W)))
    val out = Output(UInt(64.W))
  })
  io.out := io.input.reduce(_ + _)
}
```

Comment: This uses the Scala short hand.  The more explicit way of using reduce would be `.reduce { (acc, value) => acc + value }`

Comment: Also note the width inferencing behavior. `+` is truncating addition (ie. the result is the same width as the widest of the operands) which looks like the desired behavior here. In the case where you want expanding addition (the result is 1 bit wider than the widest operand), you should use `+&`.

Comment: This is nice except when using +&, the infered width is not what needed minimally. For example, a list of 4 UInt(8.W) will give UInt(11.W), but  UInt(10.W) is ideal. Any easier way to do that? I tried List().par.reduce, works for n=4, but not n=8,16...

Comment: There is a feature that supports I think you want, and that is the experimental chisel3's Interval type in which bounds of wires are stated rather than bit widths. The width inference in the firrtl compiler does a better job of figuring how many bits are necessary in operations like this